# マルチドメインSSL証明書の運用について

Tags: apache, ssl, https, browser

現在、複数のドメイン（グローバルIPアドレス、サーバ自体も別）を持つサービスを管理しております。

費用面から、個別のシングルドメインSSL証明書をもたせるのではなく、マルチドメインSSL証明書に切り替えて、複数ドメインの証明書をまとめることを検討しています。

このような運用に切り替えた場合、運用上で発生する（した）問題などがあれば教えて頂けますか。

- アクセス元クライアントはブラウザで、サポート切れOS（Windows XPなど）やガラケーなどはサポート外です。そのため、一般的なマルチドメイン証明書の導入に伴うトラブルは起きないと考えております。
- 秘密鍵が同一になることで、漏洩した時の影響が大きいだろうと考えております。
- 仮に切り替えて問題が起こり、シングルドメイン証明書に戻してもクライアント（ブラウザなど）で特に問題は起きないという認識です。